# git-svn: how to change the svn username on dcommit?

Tags: git-svn

I cloned a SVN repository into a git repository using `git svn clone`. At that point in time, I did not have a username at that site and hence didn't use the `--username` option of `clone`. As I can now commit to the SVN repository with my new username, I would like to add that username. Without it, `dcommit` simply fails:

```
% LANG=C git svn dcommit 
Committing to <THE URL> ...
RA layer request failed: Server sent unexpected return value (405 Method Not Allowed) in response to MKACTIVITY request for '/svn/!svn/act/0ceca4c5-f7b4-4432-94be-0485559a6040' at /usr/lib/git-core/git-svn line 945.
```

Is there a way to tell git about a new username? The [git-svn manual](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html) doesn't seem to help: adding a username is only allowed on `init` and `branch`. I don't know how git works with SVN internally, but I guess there should be a way to add a username afterwards.

Note that I am using SVN over http.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use this procedure (from the git svn manpage) to create a clone of your existing svn repository, but change the git svn init step so that it specifies a username.  Your new git-svn repository will then have a username.

```
# Clone locally - make sure the refs/remotes/ space matches the server

    mkdir project
    cd project
    git init
    git remote add origin server:/pub/project
    git config --replace-all remote.origin.fetch '+refs/remotes/*:refs/remotes/*'
    git fetch
# Prevent fetch/pull from remote git server in the future,
# we only want to use git svn for future updates
    git config --remove-section remote.origin
# Create a local branch from one of the branches just fetched

    git checkout -b master FETCH_HEAD
# Initialize 'git svn' locally (be sure to use the same URL and -T/-b/-t options as were used on server)
    git svn init --username my_new_name http://svn.example.com/project
# Pull the latest changes from Subversion
    git svn rebase
```

Comment: In addition to this, I used http://theadmin.org/articles/git-svn-switch-to-a-different-a-svn-url/ to change the URL after setting a new username.

Comment: how can i change the username? In my local git commits, I get my username and email id. But when i push to svn, I get the username of the guy who had setup git svn in my system. I tried to run 'git svn --username <myusername>, but i see message that 'GIT_SVN_ID may be set in the environmet .........(a long message)'.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the username in the `dcommit` command, e.g.

```
git svn dcommit --username=isapir
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you specify a username, you would not be able to dcommit a merge commit, not before Git 2.16.x/2.17 (Q1 2018).
That is because "`git svn dcommit`" did not take into account the fact that a
`svn+ssh://` URL with a `username@` (typically used for pushing) refers
to the same SVN repository without the `username@` and failed when
`svn.pushmergeinfo` option is set.

See [commit 8aaed89](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8aaed892fd50f2d82caebe964994e0d55695667a) (15 Sep 2017) by [Jason Merrill (`jwmerrill`)](https://github.com/jwmerrill).
<sup>(Merged by [Jason Merrill -- `jwmerrill` --](https://github.com/jwmerrill) in [commit 8aaed89](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8aaed892fd50f2d82caebe964994e0d55695667a), 17 Sep 2017)</sup>

> ### `git-svn`: fix `svn.pushmergeinfo` handling of `svn+ssh` usernames.
>
> Previously, `svn dcommit` of a merge with `svn.pushmergeinfo` set would
>   get error messages like
>
> ```
> merge parent <X> for <Y> is on branch svn+ssh://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/trunk, 
> which is not under the git-svn root svn+ssh://jason@gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc!"
> ```
>
> So, let's call `remove_username` (as we do for `svn info`) before comparing
>   rooturl to `branchurl`.