# DCommit As A Different User Using git svn

Tags: git-svn

I have an svn feature branch that came from trunk but was supposed to have come from a production branch. The result is that there are commits in this branch that shouldn't be there since the production branch is long lived and there are commits in trunk that have not gone to production.

I need to create a new branch from production then apply the commits one by one from the old feature branch to the new one and resolve conflicts as I go.

(Lets ignore the issue of staircase branching for this question. I am actually trying to fix it by squashing trunk with production and then branching from this updated trunk).

I figured it would be easier to do this with git than svn as I can see where I am offline before finishing.

As I go along I realise that the commits I make in this new branch locally in git are going to be under my username then when I dcommit it will look like I did all the work in this feature branch in svn.

Is there any way to make dcommit use different svn users as it pushes the commits to svn?

Comment: I believe `git-svn` uses your default `svn` credentials (same mechanism that direct `svn` uses). You could modify those credentials with another username and password, then make some commits and dcommit those under the new user, but otherwise, no, you cannot preconfogure certain commits to use another user as commiter, that would be a security issue anyway.

Comment: ...however, as always, I could be (and probably am) wrong... here is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11956986/git-svn-how-to-change-the-svn-username-on-dcommit

Comment: ...also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605519/does-git-svn-store-svn-passwords